# Show all Windows Services on agent with Operations Manager 2012 R2

Tags: system-center

I am pretty new to Operations Manager. I've installed the remote agent on a server and the Windows Firewall on that server is configured to accept all requests from the Managemen Server.

After adding the Windows Server 2012 R2 Management Pack with dependencies I thought is was as easy as installing the agent and then SCOM will show me some data in the folders on the left.

Windows Service and Process Monitoring -> Windows Service State contains only two services running on the Management Server and nothing else.

After some experimenting I finally managed to get 1 service on the remote computer to display there but it seems like I have added that service as a type or something, rather than the actual service.

Could someone kickstart me a bit ?

My first milestone with Operations Manager is monitoring the state, CPU utility and memory usage of Windows Services. I want to install the remote agent on servers and choose to monitor all or selected services on that computer.

---

I used the Authoring -> Windows Service -> Add Monitoring Wizard to add the service and it is monitoring.

If I now want to create a new State View somewhere, the service appeard in the target list along with generic items like "Health Service", ".NET Application Monitoring" and "IIS 8 Server Monitoring" and this does not seem right.

Comment: Unless you've set SCOM up to auto-approve pending Management Agents, that's the first thing you need to do. Administration -> Pending Management -> Manual Agent Install -> Right-click "Approve"

Comment: I used push install from the Management server so I think it was automatically approved. The Pending Management list is empty. The server, I can see it in the Agent Managed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCOM does have a bit of a curve to it. In your case I just have a few comments that might help you get started.

SCOM can install agent software remotely to machines, this one of the few times the server will initiate a connection to the agent machine. Most of the time it’s the agents responsibility to initiate (and keep alive) a connection to the MS (Management Server).  The agent continuously watches to see if a new configuration is available for it and will download and process it when available.  You can view this happening in the agents “operations manager” windows event log.

The SCOM configuration is made of scripts and other info to tell the agent what to do (management packets).  Main objects you’ll work with are Discoveries (do I have X on the machine via registry check/file /wmi check etc), Rules (did something happen? Or Collect X performance counter), Monitors (is the light switch on or off).  This is overly simplified but you get the idea.

In your case the “Windows service” template creates a bundle of these for you.  If you right click on the template in the authoring view you can dig down into all the objects that make up that template.  If you target say all “all windows computers” in the template, all agents will download this config, check to see if they have the service installed (discovery), then report the health status of the service (monitor) and capture metric data such as cpu/memory if configured in the template (rules).  After a few minutes you will see the monitors health status start to populate in the “Windows Service State” view.

Getting back to your question, you need to create a template for each service you want to monitor.  SCOM will discovery these on the applicable servers that you target.

Comment: Thank you. What puzzled me was that I thought I could monitor all types of Windows Services by just monitoring the server. Now I know I how to make templates for different services.